# Is tensorflow lazy?

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say you have some piece of code like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
f = h*y + z*t  #Just some expression involving other tensors.
e = ... # some expression that does not involve f. 
result = tf.select(b, e, f)

sess.run(result)
```

b is a boolean tensor of the same shape as e and f. 
If all the elements of b evaluate to true, we don't need
f and the result will just be (or be equal to) e.

The question: when the session is run with *result*, and the elements of e are all true, is f evaluated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR:** TensorFlow is strict, so both `e` and `f` will be evaluated before the `tf.select()` node executes.

This has caused some confusion. TensorFlow first prunes the dataflow graph based on which operations are *statically* required to produce the values that are fetched (i.e. the arguments to `sess.run()`). Once the graph has been pruned, however, the runtime uses strict execution, whereby all of the inputs to an operation (such as `tf.select()`) must have been computed before that operation can execute.

There is experimental support for conditional execution in the [`tf.control_flow_ops`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py) module, using the [`tf.control_flow_ops.cond()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0f7dbaa217b9a990c43f6a0c702844c1738d4361/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L595) function, but this is sparsely documented at present.